# Shell Script to find the max. number within string

Tags: bash, grep

I have a list of trace file within the directory /instance-1/trace/ (logs file) inside each trace I have a common text followed by some numbers, this may be repeating within the trace file.

e.g

text contains:

```
For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3
```

I need to find this string with maximum one

```
For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2

For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 7

For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 5
```

Result should return
For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 7

It should trace all the file within the /instance-1/trace/ directory and find out maximum value

I just tried within the `/instance-1/trace/`

```
grep -r "For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is" ./*
```

I got below result but very difficult to find maximum one manually.

```
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:09.587 [646b:351b4c5dd5f2655a035303d6]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:09.906 [6b5c:351b4c5dd6f274729b136ad7]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:10.052 [646b:361b4c5dd7f2e6c9ca3c5600]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:10.487 [7358:361b4c5dd8f2d9235dd8f517]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:10.771 [5ed7:361b4c5dd9f23edba4fa8f60]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:11.145 [7259:371b4c5ddaf2a716aebd782a]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:11.392 [5ed7:371b4c5ddbf25da83a425098]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:11.713 [6b5c:371b4c5dddf2d7c43874b335]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:11.888 [731c:371b4c5ddef29e04442ee731]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:12.674 [71bf:381b4c5ddff20094166f6893]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:12.966 [5ed7:381b4c5de0f27bd259a6f485]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:13.241 [72fc:391b4c5de3f2f63d9528d2a9]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:13.635 [7196:391b4c5de4f2ae81238c4f93]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 1 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:13.686 [72fe:391b4c5de5f2bf0a96e33a8b]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:14.201 [72fc:3a1b4c5de8f2c076364ad6f3]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:14.525 [6b5c:3a1b4c5deaf2855760b22c4b]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:14.678 [7196:3a1b4c5decf2fff0884c4592]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 4 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:14.936 [7357:3a1b4c5dedf244d43697b6a5]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:15.190 [72fc:3b1b4c5deef2922ac607f5db]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:15.462 [71f1:3b1b4c5deff28a823d628247]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 2
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:15.545 [7358:3b1b4c5df0f29095c7c21232]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is 3 
./node01_20190808120500.trc:INFO    08/Aug/2019:14:53:16.407 [646b:3c1b4c5df3f2cb720a5c29c8]              For an API WebAPI v1.2 with
```

some more same

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the maximum per file? Instead of recursively greping, I'd go to processing each so:

```bash
find . -type f -name 'node01_20*.trc' -exec sh -c \
"grep -H 'For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is' {} |sort -n |tail -1" \;
```

or alternatively (but I think I should go with a while loop)

```bash
find . -type f -name 'node01_20*.trc' -exec sh -c \
"grep -h 'For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is' {} |cut -c 128- |sort -n |tail -1; echo ' {}'" \;
```

If you know AWK, it may be a better candidate for such thing.

Answer (score -1):

you can use param --colour to display search string in result

Comment: Hello Thomas Thanks for the comment but this will get same list of strings with different colour that's it, again I have to find manually which one has max value.

Comment: egrep -r -Hno "For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is ([0-9]+)" ./*|sort -n -f10|tail -f10|tail

Fields : filename:linenumber:string

Comment: sorry typo: egrep -r -Hno "For an API WebAPI v1.2 with concurrent request is ([0-9]+)" ./*|sort -n -f10|tail -f1

Comment: @ThomasE Your answer doesn't address the question, but you make a comment that does. Replace your answer with the comment you made.